# Powershell terminal error "couldn't create connection to server"

Tags: visual-studio-code

Unable to use the powershell terminal in vscode. Get the error:
PowerShell Editor Services client: couldn't create connection to server.

So far I have uninstalled and deleted VSCode Program, ProgramData and LocalAppData directories, reinstalled and has not resolved the problem. I have deleted powershell profiles, also does not resolve. Powershell execution policy is set to remotesigned (not restricted).

Pretty much at my whit's end so hence posting here.

#### Here is the debug log:

```
DEBUG: Logging started
DEBUG: Beginning EndProcessing block
VERBOSE: Removing PSReadLine
DEBUG: Creating host configuration
DEBUG: Determining REPL kind
DEBUG: REPL configured as PSReadLine
DEBUG: Configuring LSP transport
DEBUG: Configuring debug transport
DEBUG: Session file writer created
VERBOSE: Adding AssemblyResolve event handler for new AssemblyLoadContext dependency loading
VERBOSE: Loading EditorServices
VERBOSE: PID: 12148
VERBOSE: 
== Build Details ==
- Editor Services version: 3.13.0
- Build origin:            Release
- Build commit:            b0d71da6a0bdcbd26b240fc1d97e6e2f00561688
- Build time:              10/10/2023 12:00:00 AM      

VERBOSE: 
== Host Startup Configuration Details ==
 - Host name:                 Visual Studio Code Host  
 - Host version:              2023.8.0
 - Host profile ID:           Microsoft.VSCode
 - PowerShell host type:      System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHost

 - REPL setting:              PSReadLine
 - Session details path:      c:\Users\jason\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode.powershell\sessions\PSES-VSCode-18500-567145.json
 - Bundled modules path:      c:\Users\jason\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2023.8.0\modules        
 - Additional modules:        PowerShellEditorServices.VSCode
 - Feature flags:

 - Log path:                  c:\Users\jason\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode.powershell\logs\1698378269-579beb5d-3a72-48b5-8ccc-a89330bde3cd1698378268155\EditorServices.log
 - Minimum log level:         Diagnostic

 - Profile paths:
   + AllUsersAllHosts:       C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\profile.ps1
   + AllUsersCurrentHost:    C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1
   + CurrentUserAllHosts:    C:\Users\jason\OneDrive\Documents\PowerShell\profile.ps1
   + CurrentUserCurrentHost: C:\Users\jason\OneDrive\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1  

DEBUG: Loaded into load context "Default" System.Runtime.Loader.DefaultAssemblyLoadContext #0: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics, Version=7.3.7.500, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
DEBUG: Loaded into load context "Default" System.Runtime.Loader.DefaultAssemblyLoadContext #0: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility, Version=7.3.7.500, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
DEBUG: Loaded into load context "Default" System.Runtime.Loader.DefaultAssemblyLoadContext #0: Microsoft.PowerShell.MarkdownRender, Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
DEBUG: Loaded into load context "Default" System.Runtime.Loader.DefaultAssemblyLoadContext #0: System.Net.Http, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
DEBUG: Loaded into load context "Default" System.Runtime.Loader.DefaultAssemblyLoadContext #0: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management, Version=7.3.7.500, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
DEBUG: Loaded into load context "Default" System.Runtime.Loader.DefaultAssemblyLoadContext #0: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security, Version=7.3.7.500, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
DEBUG: Loaded into load context "Default" System.Runtime.Loader.DefaultAssemblyLoadContext #0: Microsoft.WSMan.Management, Version=7.3.7.500, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
DEBUG: Loaded into load context "Default" System.Runtime.Loader.DefaultAssemblyLoadContext #0: Microsoft.WSMan.Runtime, Version=7.3.7.500, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
VERBOSE: 
== Console Details ==
 - Console input encoding: OEM United States
 - Console output encoding: OEM United States
 - PowerShell output encoding: Unicode (UTF-8)

VERBOSE: 
== Environment Details ==
 - OS description:  Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045       
 - OS architecture: X64
 - Process bitness: 64

VERBOSE: 
== PowerShell Details ==
- PowerShell version: 7.3.7
- Language mode:      FullLanguage

VERBOSE: Updated PSModulePath to: 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;c:\program files\powershell\7\Modules;C:\W10PowerLab\PSModules;C:\Users\jason\OneDrive\Documents\PowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules;C:\Users\jason\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2023.2.1\modules;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Microsoft Application Virtualization\Sequencer\AppvPkgConverter;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Microsoft Application Virtualization\Sequencer\AppvSequencer;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Microsoft Application Virtualization\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Azure Information Protection\Powershell;c:\Users\jason\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2023.8.0\modules'
DEBUG: Validating configuration
VERBOSE: Loading PowerShell Editor Services
DEBUG: Assembly resolve event fired for Microsoft.PowerShell.EditorServices, Version=3.13.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
VERBOSE: Loading PSES DLL using new assembly load context
DEBUG: Loaded into load context "PsesLoadContext" Microsoft.PowerShell.EditorServices.Hosting.PsesLoadContext 
#1: Microsoft.PowerShell.EditorServices, Version=3.13.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
VERBOSE: Starting EditorServices
DEBUG: Loaded into load context "PsesLoadContext" Microsoft.PowerShell.EditorServices.Hosting.PsesLoadContext 
#1: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
DEBUG: Loaded into load context "PsesLoadContext" Microsoft.PowerShell.EditorServices.Hosting.PsesLoadContext 
#1: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
DEBUG: Loaded into load context "PsesLoadContext" Microsoft.PowerShell.EditorServices.Hosting.PsesLoadContext 
#1: Serilog, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10
DEBUG: Loaded into load context "PsesLoadContext" Microsoft.PowerShell.EditorServices.Hosting.PsesLoadContext 
#1: Serilog.Sinks.Async, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10
DEBUG: Loaded into load context "PsesLoadContext" Microsoft.PowerShell.EditorServices.Hosting.PsesLoadContext 
#1: Serilog.Extensions.Logging, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10
DEBUG: Loaded into load context "PsesLoadContext" Microsoft.PowerShell.EditorServices.Hosting.PsesLoadContext 
#1: Serilog.Sinks.File, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24c2f752a8e58a10
DEBUG: Loaded into load context "PsesLoadContext" Microsoft.PowerShell.EditorServices.Hosting.PsesLoadContext #1: Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
DEBUG: Creating/running editor services
DEBUG: Creating startup info object
VERBOSE: Starting server, deregistering host logger and registering shutdown listener
PowerShell Extension v2023.8.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

https://aka.ms/vscode-powershell
Type 'help' to get help.

### Editor Services Log
[Warn  - 10:49:33 PM] OmniSharp.Extensions.LanguageServer.Server.LspServerOutputFilter: Tried to send request or notification before initialization was completed and will be sent later OmniSharp.Extensions.JsonRpc.RequestCancelled | @Request='OmniSharp.Extensions.JsonRpc.RequestCancelled'
[Error - 2:12:40 AM] Server initialization failed.
  Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
  Code: -32097 
[Error - 2:12:40 AM] Connection to PowerShell Editor Services (the Extension Terminal) was closed. See below prompt to restart!
[Error - 2:12:40 AM] PowerShell Editor Services client: couldn't create connection to server.
  Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
  Code: -32097
```

#### Extension Log

```
10/26/2023 10:44:29 PM [VERBOSE] - Log file path: 'file:///c%3A/Users/jason/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode.powershell/logs/1698378269-579beb5d-3a72-48b5-8ccc-a89330bde3cd1698378268155/vscode-powershell.log'

10/26/2023 10:44:29 PM [VERBOSE] - Loaded settings:
{
  "powerShellAdditionalExePaths": {},
  "powerShellDefaultVersion": "",
  "promptToUpdatePowerShell": true,
  "suppressAdditionalExeNotFoundWarning": false,
  "startAsLoginShell": {
    "osx": true,
    "linux": false
  },
  "startAutomatically": true,
  "enableProfileLoading": true,
  "helpCompletion": "BlockComment",
  "scriptAnalysis": {
    "enable": true,
    "settingsPath": "PSScriptAnalyzerSettings.psd1"
  },
  "debugging": {
    "createTemporaryIntegratedConsole": false
  },
  "developer": {
    "featureFlags": [],
    "bundledModulesPath": "../../PowerShellEditorServices/module",
    "editorServicesLogLevel": "Diagnostic",
    "editorServicesWaitForDebugger": false,
    "waitForSessionFileTimeoutSeconds": 240
  },
  "codeFormatting": {
    "autoCorrectAliases": false,
    "avoidSemicolonsAsLineTerminators": false,
    "preset": "Custom",
    "openBraceOnSameLine": true,
    "newLineAfterOpenBrace": true,
    "newLineAfterCloseBrace": true,
    "pipelineIndentationStyle": "NoIndentation",
    "whitespaceBeforeOpenBrace": true,
    "whitespaceBeforeOpenParen": true,
    "whitespaceAroundOperator": true,
    "whitespaceAfterSeparator": true,
    "whitespaceBetweenParameters": false,
    "whitespaceInsideBrace": true,
    "addWhitespaceAroundPipe": true,
    "trimWhitespaceAroundPipe": false,
    "ignoreOneLineBlock": true,
    "alignPropertyValuePairs": true,
    "useConstantStrings": false,
    "useCorrectCasing": false
  },
  "integratedConsole": {
    "showOnStartup": true,
    "startInBackground": false,
    "focusConsoleOnExecute": true,
    "useLegacyReadLine": false,
    "forceClearScrollbackBuffer": false,
    "suppressStartupBanner": false,
    "startLocation": "Panel"
  },
  "sideBar": {
    "CommandExplorerVisibility": true,
    "CommandExplorerExcludeFilter": []
  },
  "pester": {
    "useLegacyCodeLens": true,
    "outputVerbosity": "FromPreference",
    "debugOutputVerbosity": "Diagnostic"
  },
  "buttons": {
    "showRunButtons": true,
    "showPanelMovementButtons": false
  },
  "cwd": "",
  "enableReferencesCodeLens": true,
  "analyzeOpenDocumentsOnly": false
}

10/26/2023 10:44:29 PM [VERBOSE] - Creating log directory at: 'file:///c%3A/Users/jason/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode.powershell/logs/1698378269-579beb5d-3a72-48b5-8ccc-a89330bde3cd1698378268155'

10/26/2023 10:44:29 PM [NORMAL] - Visual Studio Code: v1.83.1 64-bit on Windows 64-bit

10/26/2023 10:44:29 PM [NORMAL] - PowerShell Extension: v2023.8.0

10/26/2023 10:44:29 PM [VERBOSE] - Session status changing from 'Not Started' to 'Starting'.

10/26/2023 10:44:29 PM [VERBOSE] - Finding PowerShell...

10/26/2023 10:44:29 PM [VERBOSE] - Session status changing from 'Starting' to 'Starting'.

10/26/2023 10:44:29 PM [NORMAL] - Starting 'PowerShell (x64)' at: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe

10/26/2023 10:44:29 PM [VERBOSE] - Starting process: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command Import-Module 'c:\Users\jason\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2023.8.0\modules\PowerShellEditorServices\PowerShellEditorServices.psd1'; Start-EditorServices -HostName 'Visual Studio Code Host' -HostProfileId 'Microsoft.VSCode' -HostVersion '2023.8.0' -AdditionalModules @('PowerShellEditorServices.VSCode') -BundledModulesPath 'c:\Users\jason\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2023.8.0\modules' -EnableConsoleRepl -StartupBanner "PowerShell Extension v2023.8.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

https://aka.ms/vscode-powershell
Type 'help' to get help.
" -LogLevel 'Diagnostic' -LogPath 'c:\Users\jason\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode.powershell\logs\1698378269-579beb5d-3a72-48b5-8ccc-a89330bde3cd1698378268155\EditorServices.log' -SessionDetailsPath 'c:\Users\jason\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode.powershell\sessions\PSES-VSCode-18500-567145.json' -FeatureFlags @() 

10/26/2023 10:44:30 PM [NORMAL] - PowerShell process started with PID: 12148

10/26/2023 10:44:30 PM [VERBOSE] - Waiting for session file: file:///c%3A/Users/jason/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode.powershell/sessions/PSES-VSCode-18500-567145.json

10/26/2023 10:44:32 PM [VERBOSE] - Session file found.

10/26/2023 10:44:32 PM [VERBOSE] - Session details: {
  "status": "started",
  "languageServiceTransport": "NamedPipe",
  "languageServicePipeName": "\\\\.\\pipe\\PSES_5hfyzuou.wmo",
  "debugServiceTransport": "NamedPipe",
  "debugServicePipeName": "\\\\.\\pipe\\PSES_owsgi5cp.5yd",
  "powerShellVersion": "7.3.7"
}

10/26/2023 10:44:32 PM [VERBOSE] - Connecting to language service...

10/26/2023 10:44:32 PM [VERBOSE] - Language service connected.

10/27/2023 2:12:39 AM [WARNING] - PowerShell process terminated or Extension Terminal was closed, PID: 12148

10/27/2023 2:12:39 AM [VERBOSE] - Disposing PowerShell process with PID: 12148

10/27/2023 2:12:40 AM [VERBOSE] - Session status changing from 'Starting' to 'Failed'.

10/27/2023 2:12:40 AM [ERROR] - Never finished startup!
```

Normally the powershell terminal will load without error.